# htaccess get folder one level below

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have some folders in root of my server:

```
css/
js/
gfx/
new_www/
...
```

and some more. Assuming that I want in folder new_www copy of current page, but force it to use some things from root folder (for example gfx folder). I've tried following with .htaccess but its not working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /new_www/_js/(.*) /_js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule /new_www/gfx/(.*) /gfx/$1 [L]
```

What am I doing wrong? .htaccess is placed in root of folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please understand that RewriteRule doesn't match leading slash in an URI when used in .htaccess. Your code should be replaced with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^new_www/(_js/.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^new_www/(gfx/.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

OR even better will be to have just one rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^new_www/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```